# Splitting a line in Python into 3 different parts

Tags: python

I have a text file. The lines go like  this

```
word1 word2 <sentence>
```

How do I just get the sentence in python?

Comment: Isn't a sentence also made from words?

Comment: @Katpoes - yes , the sentence has multiple spaces

Comment: so you want the content from every line apart from the first 2 words?

Comment: @Katpoes word2 and sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to split out the first couple of items on each line but still use the rest of the sentence.  In other words, you only want to make two splits.

The [`split` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes an optional `maxsplit` argument that allows you to only split on a set number of occurrences.  However, because it's a positional argument, we need to explicitly specify the delimiter (`None` if you want to split on whitespace -- the default).

For example, we can do:

```
x = 'The quick fox jumps over the lazy brown dog'
print x.split(None, 2)
```

and get:

```
['The', 'quick', 'fox jumps over the lazy brown dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # You can change it to [2:] to skip the first 2 words.
        print line.split(' ')[1:]
# I suppose something like this?
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to split by whitespace, then skip the first two words with a slice:

```
print line.split()[2:] # all but first two words in line
```